# Boxed equation with empheq: adding text outside box

Tags: equations, captions, boxes, framed, empheq

I'm trying to have a box around my align environment, so I do the following:

```
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
  equations
\end{empheq}
```

This works fine, but I would like to have above the box text as some kind of title for the box.

So I try

```
 \newcommand*\textfbox[2][Title]{
     \begin{center}
        \text{#2}
     \end{center}
     \fbox{#1}
 }
```

And then replace `box=\fbox` with `box={\textfbox{the title that I want}}`. This does not work, it places the text next to the box and not above the box, so I have tried inserting `\par` or `\newline` but to no avail.

Comment: It is good that you included some code. Even better would be minimal working examples---chunks of code complete in themselves that can be copied and compiled and that manifest your issue.

Comment: First, it should be `box=\textfbox{The title you want}` note the lack of backslash and the curly braces around your argument...

Comment: T I edited the title to make it reflect the more specifc problem you are having.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using in a wrong way the parameters, first of all: `#1` refers to the optional argument, `#2` to the mandatory one. Moreover, there's no `centering` environment and the `\centering` command is useless here.

```
\newcommand*\textfbox[2][Title]{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}#1\\\fbox{#2}\end{tabular}}

\begin{empheq}[box={\textfbox[A different title]}]{align}
  equations
\end{empheq}
```